# Equation for spatial gradient - what does this notation mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, gradient-descent

I'm working my way through a paper on Super Resolution, and am having trouble figuring out how to evaluate this equation for the spatial gradient:

[image]

The summation limits, wx & wy, are the window size (lets assume wx=2;wy=2)

Ix & Iy are horizontal and vertical gradients of the image. I'm assuming these are actually indexed by (x,y) but don't know that for sure.

The calculation of G should result in a 6x6 matrix for the other equations listed in the paper to make sense.

How do I calculate G?

Comment: Looks to me like you do exactly what the expression says to do: compute that $6\times6$ matrix for each pixel and add them up. You can do that component by component, if that’s easier. Observe that the matrix is symmetric and appears to be an outer product of two vectors, which you can take advantage of to reduce the work involved.

Comment: Also, please take the time to type in important parts of your question instead of simply pasting an image. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers.

Comment: @amd, would it make sense that Ix & Iy are also indexed by x,y? Otherwise these are matrices the size of the image, rather that the 5x5 window I'm operating on. Or, would they be the Ix & Iy located at the center of the window for all x,y in the sum?

Comment: Without more context, I can’t say. The meaning of $I_x$ and $I_y$ should’ve been explained somewhere in the paper. The matrix is the outer product of $(I_x,I_y,xI_x,yI_x,xI_y,yI_y)$ with itself, BTW.